# Why is the ouput in wrong unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to append `a` to `results` and it should print the plain `http://` links. I want to be able to print out results like so: `results[:4]`
I'm thankfull for any help! Thanks!

This is the code:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

results = []

def extract(soup):
 section = soup.find('section', {'class' : 'content left'})
 for post in section.findAll('article'):
   header = post.find('header', {'class' : 'loop-data'}) 
   a = header.findAll('a', href=True)
   for x in a:
    results.append(x.get('href'))
 print results

br = Browser()
url = "http://www.hotglobalnews.com/category/politics/"
page1 = br.open(url)
html1 = page1.read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)
extract(soup1)
```

This is my outcome:

```
[u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/canada-just-legalized-heroin-to-control-     drug-addiction/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/justin-trudeau-announces-deal-with-uber-uberweed/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-to-legalize-marijuana-in-all-50-states/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/obama-to-create-law-banning-words/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/trudeau-says-trump-is-a-racist-bastard/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-to-build-replica-of-guantanamo-bay-for-mexicans/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-to-legalize-incest-marriages-if-elected/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/justin-trudeau-to-build-statue-of-trudeau-in-2017/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-muslims-invented-global-warming-to-destroy-u-s-economy/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/isis-member-found-disguised-as-syrian-refugee-in-canada/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-says-he-is-more-influential-than-martin-luther-king-jr/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/obama-wears-fuck-trump-tshirt-to-white-house-barbecue/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-says-he-could-shoot-somebody/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trump-says-black-history-month-is-too-long/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/justin-trudeau-to-ban-uber-in-canada/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/justin-trudeau-accepts-comedy-central-new-years-roast/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/donald-trumps-muslim-comment-disqualifies-him-from-presidency/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/paris-terrorist-spotted-live-on-news-after-terror-attacks-on-paris/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/anonymus-hacker-collective-declares-war-on-islamic-sate-group/', u'http://www.hotglobalnews.com/paris-attacks-over-100-killed-in-gunfire-and-blasts2/']
```

Comment: Looks fine to me (except for the weird space in the first link). Unicode is not wrong, neither is the `u` prefix before the quotes.

Comment: I'm just curious how can i get rid of the `u` prefix and print out only the plain `href` links?

Comment: Just `print(x.get('href'))` or print each item in the list.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, as it put the results out of whack with the code. If you want to obscure the site you are visiting, you need to change it everywhere.

Comment: @tripleee I see. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the list you get. The `u` sigil tells you that the stuff in the string is Unicode, but that's not "wrong" in any way. Printing the string will produce the desired result (provided your OS is correctly configured to display the characters; for what looks like essentially plain ASCII strings, this should not be an issue).

Python 3 changes these things somewhat, but generally for the better. You still need to understand the difference between byte strings and Unicode strings (at least if you need to work with byte strings too), but by default all strings are Unicode, which makes good sense in this day and age.

https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html is still a good place to start, especially if you have not yet made the transition to Python 3.

Comment: ... And you should, soon. Python 2 was originally slated to be end-of-lifed next year, though it's now getting its life extended in a heart and lung machine.